# Excel, can I display different text of with a formula result in the same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to use an Excel formula to effectively replace or display a different value in the same cell...

Just to explain, this is for a weightlifting barbell calculation...
So for example...
if I type 45 into the cell to represent 45kg each side
then in number/text I want to display is 110
which is (45x2)+20

Is it possible to replace same cell value with formula result?

Comment: you can't do this with a formula, are you open to using a VBA method ?

Comment: If you type `45` into the cell `A1` and want to display `(45x2)+20=110` in `B1` then you may use a formula. But if you want to replace inserted `45` with calculated `110` in the same cell `A1` then only VBA method may solve.

Comment: PS make sure your bar weighs 20, I used this calculation for my 1 rep max for years, then realised I was using a 15kg bar ! lost 5KG over night :(

Answer (score 2):

```vb
' the range where the replace must be performed
Private Const DataAddress As String = "B1:B10"  

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Static busy As Boolean
Dim destination As String
Dim datarange As Range
Dim onecell As Range
' Check does the method is already executed for to forbid chain execution
If busy Then Exit Sub
busy = True
' Convert single-cell address to range address
If InStr(Target.Address, ":") = 0 Then
    destination = Target.Address & ":" & Target.Address
Else
    destination = Target.Address
End If
' Check does the range in interest is altered
Set datarange = Application.Intersect(Range(DataAddress), Range(destination))
If Not datarange Is Nothing Then
    ' Replace each cell in the range with new value
    For Each onecell In datarange
        onecell.Value = 2 * onecell.Value + 20
    Next
End If
' Drop busy flag
busy = False
End Sub
```

Allows to edit both single cell (by hands) and a range (copy-paste).

Do NOT check does the value inserted is a numeric value - you may add this if needed.